# Change the color of the cursor in Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013, cursor

I need to change the cursor color; I can hardly see mine (currently light green). I tried Themes, Color, Effects on the Page Layout tab with no success. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which operating system? Which version of Excel?

Comment: Using Excel 2013 with Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

#### I need to change the cursor color

You can use the code ("Highlighting The Active Cell") below.

However, there is a downside:

> There is one massive drawback, and that is that this technique will use something called "Event Procedures", which means that the macro will fire every time you move the cursor - and every time a macro fires it will clear your undo stack. So, yes, it is do-able, but you'll lose your undo facility.

Source [Can the Excel 'cursor' or 'cell outline' color be changed?](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-new-users-basics/631262-can-the-excel-cursor-or-cell-outline-color-be-changed.html)

The [RowLiner](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RowLiner.htm) add-in (by the same author as the code below) also looks interesting. This add-in has the same issue with undo:

> RowLiner will disable the Undo feature. This is a limitation imposed by the basic design of Excel and cannot be changed.

---

#### Highlighting The Active Cell

> If you want to make the active cell appear in a special color, use the
>   following code in the Workbook_`SheetSelectionChange` event of the
>   workbook.
>
> ```
> Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object,
>     ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
>     Static OldRange As Range
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 ' yellow - change as needed
>     OldRange.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
>     Set OldRange = Target
> End Sub
> ```
>
> This will change the background color of the ActiveCell to yellow
>   anytime you select a new cell, either with the mouse or with the arrow
>   keys.
>
> NOTE:  This technique has been greatly enhanced in my [RowLiner](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RowLiner.htm)
>   add-in. I strongly suggest you use [RowLiner](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/RowLiner.htm) instead.

Source [Highlighting The Active Cell](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/excelM.htm#HighlightActiveCell)

Comment: At the bottom of the page for RowLiner the author states that it also disables Undo.